# trouble with Template.leaderboard.helpers(...) syntax

Tags: meteor

Ok, been going through a tutorial on Learnable.com to learn Meteor and it seems that I've run into a spot that needs to be updated because I keep getting an error with the statement the tutorial tells me to use.

Here's the code:
    PlayersList = new Meteor.Collection('players');

```
if(Meteor.isClient){
    Template.leaderboard.player = function(){
        return "A bit of text."
    }
}

if(Meteor.isServer){

}
```

It's the `Template.leaderboard.player = function(){` part that's giving me the trouble.

Here's the error message I keep getting:

```
W20141027-10:15:05.776(-4) (blaze.js:67) Warning: Assigning helper with  
`Template.leaderboard.player = ...` is deprecated.  Use 
`Template.leaderboard.helpers(...)` instead. logging.js:65
```

So can someone tell me the correct usage here please?

TIA!

G

Answer (score 3):

That tutorial is old and uses a no-longer-supported way of assigning helpers to templates. The right way is the following:

```js
Template.leaderboard.helpers({
    player: function(){
        return "A bit of text."
    }
})
```

Comment: oh, also, I think they just released that tutorial about 2 months ago

Comment: @GaryG, I think they deprecated it about 1.5 months ago :P Great timing!

Comment: LOL @PeppeL-G, yeah GREAT timing huh? LOL Thanks for the help, I do appreciate it. :) New to Meteor and I am liking it, but since it isn't even 1.0 yet I do expect lots of changes over the next year or so. But I am liking what I'm seeing and how much easier it does make things.

Comment: He he, @GaryG, 1.0 was release two days ago :P And most of the things in it is pretty stable now; it's a two years old project, so it's pass its unstable phase.

Comment: LOL @PeppeL-G AH!!! Well the, looks like I need to update things. Thanks for letting me know. :)